# Finding matching keys in array/json jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `$.getJSON` to get data from external .json file with following content.

```js
{
 data:[
  {
   "1apps":"1",
   "abc" "xyz"
  },
  {
   "apps":"2",
   "abc" "xyz"
  },
  {
   "2apps":"3",
   "abc" "xyz"
  }
 ]   
}
```

I want to find the data which keys matching apps. In this case,  1apps, apps, 2apps will be the output.

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.map()` or `$.map()` over the data array and return the keys of the child objects that are not 'abc'.  You haven't included in your question any attempt that you have already made to solve this.

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question. We will help you fix bugs, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Comment: There are also syntax errors in the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter and then iterate on obj , then use a include function determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string

```js
var obj = {
  data: [{
      "1apps": "1",
      "abc": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "apps": "2",
      "abc": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "2apps": "3",
      "abc": "xyz"
    }
  ]
};


var list = obj["data"];
var matchedKeys = [];
list.filter(function(k, v) {
  for (var i in k) {
    if (i.includes('apps')) {
      matchedKeys.push(i);
      return k;
    }
  }
});

console.log(list)
   console.log(matchedKeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use reduce and filter to get the keys that include `apps`

```js
const obj = {
  data:[
    {
      "1apps":"1",
      "abc" :"xyz"
    },
    {
      "apps":"2",
      "abc" :"xyz"
    },
    {
      "2apps":"3",
      "abc" :"xyz"
    }
  ]
}

const res = obj.data.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(...Object.keys(b).filter(x => /apps/.test(x))), []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice but I'm not sure that `const res = obj.data.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(...Object.keys(b).filter(x => /apps/.test(x))), []);` really qualifies as "simple" to the un-initiated. There are a few things going on there, might it merit some explanation?